# Adobe AIR/FLEX programming tutorial

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I just read a good tutorial at http://cateof.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/helloworld-air-application-in-linux/ about creating simple apps with AIR/FLEX. What are some similar pages and/or good books that I can read to move from "beginner" to "novice"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruce Eckel and I have written "[First Steps in Flex](http://www.firststepsinflex.com)" which is a short getting started book.  We have also begun creating screencasts for each chapter which you can find on the [book's website](http://www.firststepsinflex.com).  Also make sure you check out [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour) which is a great way to learn through small examples.

Comment: James,

Thanks a lot. I will add a note to your resources.